# the number of lattice points

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

If f(x) - a non-negative continuous function, so the number of lattice points in area $a\leq x \leq b$, $0 < y \leq f(x)$ is equal to
$$\sum_{a\leq x \leq b}[f(x)]$$ where [f(x)] - integer part of f(x).

How could I apply this formula for a curve in polar coordinates? For example, $r = k \cdot cos(3\phi), k > 0$?

What books or articles could I read about this theme?

Comment: One possibility would be to convert the curve to rectangular coordinates and just use the rectangular version. There is no convenient definition directly from polar coordinates. If you know in addition that your shape is convex, you could compute the area and perimeter in polar coordinates and use a variant of something like Pick's Theorem.

Comment: @davidlowryduda, $y=r\cdot sin(\phi)=k\cdot cos(3\phi)\cdot sin(\phi), x = r \cdot cos(\phi) = k \cdot cos(3\phi)\cdot cos(\phi)$ and we can write for one "leaf" a formulae: $\sum_{a\leq \phi \leq b} [k\cdot cos(3\phi)\cdot cos(\phi)]$. But I don't know how to find a and b. Is it possible to find a and b? Or is it difficult way to solve?

Comment: @davidlowryduda, I have mistake at the formulae, $\sum_{a\leq \phi \leq b}[k \cdot cos(3\phi)\cdot sin(\phi)]$